# How can I make an object big by pointing another object at it in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity. How can I make an object big by just pointing another object(like a torch) at it? The object should constantly become big according to the amount of time i'm pointing the torch at it.

Comment: Not a Unity dev but I guess you'd use a raycast to find the object you're pointing the torch at. It's basically the same idea as shooting something with a gun.

Comment: Yeah you would raycast from the torch. On collision you would then modify the scale of the object as you see fit